# Office 2013 : how to remove security warning issued by protocolhandler.exe?

Tags: security, ms-word, ms-office, protocols

In our webdav implementation, we provide urls using the ms-word: protocol, such as this one:

```
ms-word:ofe|u|http://url_to_some_document.docx
```

Long story short, if MSOffice is installed (I have Office 2013), you can try the exact above command (no matter what lies after the http:// part) directly from Start/Run... (Windows R).

It brings the infamous security warning popup (french version below)

```
---------------------------
Microsoft Office
---------------------------
Certains fichiers contiennent des virus susceptibles d’endommager votre ordinateur. Vous devez vous assurer que ce fichier provient d’une source digne de confiance.

Voulez-vous ouvrir ce fichier ?

Programme : Microsoft Word

Adresse : http://url_to_some_document.docx
---------------------------
Oui   Non   
---------------------------
```

Question : how to remove this warning ?

I've been digging into this for hours, I've tried everything I found regarding the HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Common\Security DisableHyperlinkWarning value, to no avail

The ms-word: protocol launches protocolhandler.exe, which creates the popup question before launching winword.exe. How to tell protocolhandler.exe to proceed with the the request without asking this pesky question ?

Thanks!

Comment: As a clue to where to look for a solution to my problem, can you confirm that the DisableHyperlinkWarning setting is actually useful, or not, in this very case (direct running of the command `ms-word:ofe|u|http://xxx.yyy`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by adding the web site hosting documents (the url) to the trusted sites (sites de confiance) in inetcpl.cpl.

Answer (score 0):

Right from the top of my head I would see two ways to circumvent the warning message:

- Replace the default protocol handler with your own protocol handler.
- Serve the files via http instead of using the ms-word protocol.

Comment: Thanks, I hope we can avoid writing our own handler. As for using HTTP, how can I use it and continue providing the "edit in place" feature the ms-word offers? The point of all this is to allow users editing online word documents.